# Magento Cancel an order programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am creating an order using API and I want to return some qty back if customer do not want after completing the order .I know that there is an option in magento i.e credit memo but our requirement is not to create an credit memo.

I want to create a back-order like create an order with negative number product qty that I want to return OR

I want to cancel the order with particular products and their qty.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly - you need to delete some items from order. Magento API doesn't provides such functionality. All actions you can perform with orders via Magento API you can find in Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api